# Missing \begin{document}. \chapter{E Latex new blank page

Tags: latex

I started to use Latex to write my notes and I've been having some problems when I start a new chapter or blank page

```
\chapter{ECS, Lambda, Batch, Lightsail}
\section{ECS}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first time
\end{enumerate}
```

and this is my main

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\author{José Santiago Molano Perdomo}
\title{Aws Cloud Practicioneer}
\date{}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{./TeX_files/chapter01}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter02}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter03}
\include{./Tex_files/chapter04}
\include{./Tex_files/chapter05}
\include{./Tex_files/chapter06}
\include{./Tex_files/chapter07}
\include{./Tex_files/chapter08}
\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

I get this error when I try compile chaper 08

```
Undefined control sequence. \chapter
Missing \begin{document}. \chapter{E
Undefined control sequence. \section
Emergency stop.
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph
```

Comment: You don't compile the individual chapters, only the main file

Answer (score -1):

The character `é` in the author name is invalid to UTF-8. Please change to `\'{e}`

Comment: No, no, no! The document loads `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and even if it would not this is nowadays default of up-to-date tex installations! Also the error message is totally different.